# Javascript check json output is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp, json

If I have data in json like this :

```
{"items":[{"id":"2049","channel_code":"HBD","channel_name":"HBO HD"}]}
```

And if you search my data to the server could not find results like this :

```
{"items":[]}
```

Of output as above, how do I read that my data does not exist or is empty?

I have written some code that I got but have not found the results I want.

This code :

```
var data = { Name: "John Doe", Age: 25, Address: null, CityState: "Denver, CO" };
for (member in data) {
if (data[member] != null)
    //Do something
}
```

or

```
if (myObject == '') {
   alert('this object is empty');
}
```

Maybe someone can help me find a way out of this example.
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check whether your array is empty, just use the respective [`length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length):

```
if ( data['items'].length < 1 ) {
   // it's empty
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to check if `data.items.length > 0`. Assuming

```
var data = {"items":[]};
```

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Not entirely sure what you mean; of course there's JSON involved, that's what's creating the array.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist There's also a text editor involved (that's creating the code that creates the JSON string) but it's also irrelevant to the problem. Many people tag as [tag:json] any sort of standard JavaScript question just because there's JSON at some point.

Comment: if my code like this : for ( var i = 0; i < response.length; ++i ) { str = response[i].judul; str2 = response[i].waktu_mulai; } 

How i can use your code?

Comment: @BerthoJoris: I have no idea what `response` or `waktu_mulai` is. If your code is `var data = {items:[]}` you can check `if(data.items.length > 0) { /* data.items is not empty */ }`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (member in data) {
if (data[member] != null)
    //Do something
}
```

code inside `for` will not run because `length` of data is 0

```
if (myObject == '') {
   alert('this object is empty');
}
```

myObject wont be null because the object actually is there and its an empty array
you should check for `myObject.length` because its an empty array

Comment: if my code like this for extract : 

for ( var i = 0; i < response.length; ++i ) {
 str = response[i].judul;
 str2 = response[i].waktu_mulai;
}

How i can use your code?