# issue on identifying getjson response value

Tags: jquery, getjson

I have a `getjson` which logs successfully if I give correct data.value, if I give invalid data.value it shows an empty array`[]` on browser, how can I identify json returns an empty array `[]` using my getjson code, I have tried below code but not work, if I give invalid data.value. Need your help.

```
$.getJSON("http://xxx.xx.xx/mobapp/api/get-pli-details?id=" + data.value, function (result) {
    console.log('here ' + result[0].email);
    if (result[0] === null) {
        popup("<h3>M-Elec</h3>Invalid PLI ID");
    } else {
        email = result[0].email;
        userType = result[0].utype;
        name = result[0].name;
    }
});
```

Comment: You mean `if (result.length > 0)`? `result[0]=== null` doesn't work because if the array is empty `result[0]` is `undefined`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing for an empty array in JavaScript Performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509019/testing-for-an-empty-array-in-javascript-performance)

Comment: Have you put in break points in your code. That will give you a better idea.

Comment: @FelixKling : But i have checked '=== undefined' also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$.getJSON(url,function(result){
    if ( result.length == 0 ) {
        console.log("NO DATA!")
    }
});
```

Comment: @mvp: If you just say "not works", then we cannot help you further. [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) to help yourself.

Comment: @mvp so your url did not return anything right.so use success and failure promise callbacks

Answer (score 0):

Refer below links,

1. [How do I test for an empty Javascript object from JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object-from-json)
2. [How to check if JSON return is empty with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345761/how-to-check-if-json-return-is-empty-with-jquery)
3. [JQuery and JSON array - How to check if array is empty or undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382364/jquery-and-json-array-how-to-check-if-array-is-empty-or-undefined)
4. [Javascript check json output is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932590/javascript-check-json-output-is-empty)
5. [Testing for an empty array object in JSON with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334836/testing-for-an-empty-array-object-in-json-with-jquery)